# iOS Selection, Copy, Cut, Pase menu alteration

Tags: swift, uikit

Are we allowed to change the popover menu when some text in selected in our app. If so, how to do it?

I managed the use textViewSelectionChanged method but couldn't pop-up a custom menu.

Comment: See [UITextViewDelegate textView(_:editMenuForTextIn:suggestedActions:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextviewdelegate/3975940-textview)

Comment: Check : https://stackoverflow.com/a/73716864/6576315