# Using UIEditMenuInteraction in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I want to be able to create a custom menu when a user highlights or selects text from a `WebView`. Similar to this here [UIEditMenuInteraction example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73712955/using-uieditmenuinteraction-with-uitextview)

I set everything up in SwiftUI but cannot get my custom menu to show. I keep getting the standard IOS menu. I think I am implementing something wrong here but not sure what. Ive searched everywhere and there isn't any examples using `SwiftUI`.

```
import SwiftUI
import WebKit

struct ContentView: View {
var body: some View {
    WebView(url: URL(string: "https://www.google.com")!)
}
}

struct WebView: UIViewRepresentable{

    let url: URL

func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
    Coordinator()
}

class Coordinator: NSObject, WKNavigationDelegate,UIEditMenuInteractionDelegate {
    private func editMenuInteraction(_ interaction: UIEditMenuInteraction,
                             menuFor configuration: UIEditMenuConfiguration,
                             suggestedActions: [UIMenuElement]) -> UIMenu? {
        
       // var actions = suggestedActions
        
        let customMenu = UIMenu(title: "mycustom", children: [
            UIAction(title: "menuItem1") { _ in
                print("menuItem1")
            },
            UIAction(title: "menuItem2") { _ in
                print("menuItem2")
            },
            UIAction(title: "menuItem3") { _ in
                print("menuItem3")
            }
        ])
        
        //actions.append(customMenu)
        
       // return UIMenu(children: actions) // For Custom and Suggested Menu
        
        return UIMenu(children:customMenu.children)
    }
}

func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
    let webView = WKWebView()
    
    // Enable user interaction for the web view
    webView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    let menuInteracion = UIEditMenuInteraction(delegate: context.coordinator)
    webView.addInteraction(menuInteracion)
    // Create a UIContextMenuInteraction and assign the delegate
    return webView
}

func updateUIView(_ uiView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
    let request = URLRequest(url: url)
    uiView.load(request)        
}    
}
```